# Anybody knows how to add a camera widget on a Gifted chat component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Does anybody have any experience into adding a camera widget into  component in ReactNative?

Answer (score 0):

They provide this props `renderActions (Function) - Custom action button on the left of the message composer` and you need to add your camera button and integrate it by yourself (for example using this library `react-native-image-crop-picker`